# SwiftUI Printing a View

Tags: swift, printing, view, swiftui

I am attempting to print a view from swiftui to a printer.  Everything seems to work fine except when the print dialog appears the preview is an empty view.  My PrintView has a large black box with text in it just for testing but will not appear in print preview.

```swift
func fPrint() {
    let printingView = UIHostingController(rootView: PrintView()).view

    // GET VIEW AS NSDATA FOR PDF
    let pdfData:NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    let pageSize:CGRect = CGRect()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pageSize, nil)
    let pdfContext:CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

    // CREATE A SINGLE PAGE PDF
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
    printingView?.layer.render(in: pdfContext)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // SETUP PRINT INFO
    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary:nil)
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfo.OutputType.general
    printInfo.jobName = "Print Job"
    printInfo.orientation = .portrait

    // SETUP PRINT CONTROLLER
    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
    printController.printInfo = printInfo
    printController.showsNumberOfCopies = true
    printController.showsPaperSelectionForLoadedPapers = true
    printController.printingItem = pdfData
    printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: I wish I could answer. It takes far less work to show this - you simply create an app using the template and make it use NSDocument when you create it, then simply add a graphic into the ContentView. Print is already hooked up in the File menu, and shows exactly the same problem as you describe. I've filed FB7741161 feedback with Apple, but have no response. It doesn't work with Xcode 12, either.